# How to schedule the airflow DAG to run just after the end of the previous running DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have a simple `DAG` with 2 `PythonOperator` and schedule interval for 2 minutes:

```
with DAG(dag_id='example_cron', schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *', start_date=days_ago(2)) as dag:

    def task1_func(ti):
        print("start task 1")
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 70))
        print("end task 1")

    def task2_func(ti):
        print("start task 2")
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 70))
        print("end task 2")


    task1  = PythonOperator(task_id='task1', python_callable=task1_func, provide_context=True)
    task2  = PythonOperator(task_id='task2', python_callable=task2_func, provide_context=True)

task1 >> task2
```

- The `DAG` can run more than 2 minutes and this means that more than one `DAG` may run in parallel.

How can I configure the DAG to run just if the previous run has finished ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add `max_active_runs=1` to your DAG object.

```
with DAG(..., max_active_runs=1) as dag:
```

Not part of your question but please note that `days_ago(2)` is deprecated and in any case you should not use dynamic dates for `start_date` (see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date))